# Организация безопасности

Tags: java, безопасность

Добрый день.

Есть приложение на Java. Его надо защитить. Создать роли с паролями. И ограничивать доступ к endpoint.

Приложение не на Spring.

Как это можно сделать (пример или идея)?

Comment: Использовать [Spring Security](https://projects.spring.io/spring-security/)

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev а как имя пользователя передаются в запросе? Как хранить роли в базе и устанавливать соответствия с endpoint я уже нашел.

Comment: Обычно имя пользователя передается один раз при аутентификации, после чего пользователю выдается сессионный токен, который он присылает на сервер с каждым запросом. Как разновидность этого подхода - токены JWT, которые содержат информацию о роли и не требуют выяснения роли пользователя на сервере.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предлагаю посмотреть [Apache Shiro](https://shiro.apache.org/), решение не завязанное на Spring-инфраструктуру.

Вот тут можно посмотреть пример веб-приложения, где используется Apache Shiro - https://github.com/peneksglazami/chgk.
Конфигурацию можно выполнять в простых [ini-файлах](https://github.com/peneksglazami/chgk/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/shiro.ini).
Подключение Shiro выполняется путём объявления листенера и фильтра в [web.xml](https://github.com/peneksglazami/chgk/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml). Для хранения связок "user-role-permission" можно использовать как предлагаемые из коробки источники данных так и [собственные реализации](https://github.com/peneksglazami/chgk/blob/master/src/main/java/org/cherchgk/security/realms/HibernateRealm.java) интерфейса `org.apache.shiro.realm.AuthorizingRealm`.